# I made a REST API in SpringBoot and Now I am confused while adding a feature

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, spring-mvc

I have made a REST API in spring boot which is maintaining 4 models : Blog Posts, Comments on Posts, User Profiles, and Roles. Currently the blog posts can be deleted only by the admin and not the user who created it, I want to add this functionality that the post can be deleted by the creator which requires login in the first place, so how can I implement that ?

Here is my User Model :

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

Here is my Posts Model :

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

@Entity
@Table(
        name="Posts", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"title"})}
)
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Title", nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "Description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "Content", nullable = false)
    private String content;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Here is my Delete Post Endpoint :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<String> deletePostById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    postService.deletePostById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Post Deleted Successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Edit : Finally I was able to Configure it out here its how

```
private User getUser() {
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    Authentication auth = context.getAuthentication();
    return userRepository.findUserByEmail(auth.getName()).orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a method which checks whether the user is logged in? Do you have a method which checks whether a post is owned by a user?

Comment: I can add user_id in the posts table which will track the creator for me but I don't have any method currently to check which user is logged in. One method is that in passing every request I pass the username and password and then the repository can load the entire user for me using that email itself

Comment: So, in order to have a post-owner relationship, you will need to somehow store it. If you consider a `user_id` as a new field adequate (an idea I agree with), then do so. When that's done, you will be able to load the post by `id` and check whether a given user is its owner.

Comment: As about the other part of the solution I think you are slightly confused. We already have a user in your situation, that is, the one who sent the request for `deletePostById` and you already have this user loaded by username/password, which is a necessary prerequisite for `hasRole` to function properly.

Comment: You will need to end up with something like this: `hasRole('ADMIN') || (myPost.user_id == currentUser.id)`. You will of course need `currentUser` to be existent and properly initialized and you will need to remove the `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")` line, because that restricts the right of post removal to admins, whereas you want to expand this right for the owners as well besides admins.

Comment: In a REST environment you don't log in a user as this ultimately leads to the server needing to manage client state which violates the stateless constraints and makes scaling way harder. Instead you send the user credentials (or some form of token) on each request, lookup and load the user once the request was received and then trigger your actual business logic. Spring Boot usually supports this via Spring Security where it connects it does the user-lookup and authorization checks via `@PreAuthorize` and stuff like that automatically for you in the back

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to store who created the post if the authors should be able to change/delete it.

Then you could use @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN') || hasRole('USER')") in case your user role is named USER and in the method simply check if it's an admin or if the post is by the logged in user. You can retrieve auth infos via `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`. In an answer above you also have a suggestion for comparing the user's id with the id of the user that posted.

If you really need/want to do it via you could even create your own bean implementing it. See https://medium.com/@islamboulila/how-to-create-a-custom-security-expression-method-in-spring-security-e5b6353f062f if you need an explanation for this.